# javascript if..else statement should work but it doesn't

Tags: javascript, html, date, if-statement

I got an order from school so I've tried to make them. This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Lab 08</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Lab 08</h1>
<script>
    //0:begin
    var vandaag=new Date(); //1 //vandaag date.now(in mill sec) of new date
    document.write("vandaag is:"+vandaag+"<br>");//2
    var factuur=new Date("2021-6-16");//3
    var termijn=new Date(86400000*30);
    document.write("factuurdatum is:",factuur,"<br>");
    var betaaltijd=(factuur.getTime()+termijn.getTime());//6
    var eenDag=86400000;
    var betaaldatum=new Date(betaaltijd);//7
    document.write("betaaldatum is:"+betaaldatum+"<br>");//8


    vandaag1=vandaag.getTime();
    betaaldatum1=betaaldatum.getTime();

    if(vandaag1<betaaldatum1){//9a
        alert("meld incassobureau");//9b
        break;//9c
    }
    else{
        var tijd=((betaaldatum.getTime()-vandaag.getTime())/eenDag);
        document.write("u hebt nog "+tijd.toFixed(0)+ " dagen om te betalen");//11
        break;//12
    }

</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

The if..else statement doesn't work as expected. I put this question to my teacher but he doesn't get it either. Maybe one of you can give the solution?

Comment: "*the if else statement doesn't work*" Ok, what *specifically* is wrong with it? It's not quite clear what exactly you expected to happen, or what is actually happening with this code. Please edit your question to add this and all other pertinent debugging information, in accordance with [ask]. Please also edit the snippet in your question to be a [mre] - there seems to be a lot of extraneous code that isn't relevant to the problem at hand, which can distract viewers of your question and decrease your chances of getting helpful responses.

Comment: `break` statement can only be used in loops and your `if else` statement is not inside any loop.

Comment: Even if you press "Run code snippet" you can see what's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has an error in it, which is the use of `break` statements within the `if` and `else` clauses.  If you remove the `break`s, it should work.

[`break` statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) can only be used within `for`/`while` loops and `switch` statements.  You can't use them (and don't need them) in `if`/`else` statements.

If you click "run code snippet" on your example, it shows the error message `Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal break statement` which would help you find this issue.  Also, if you [open your browser's JavaScript console](https://balsamiq.com/support/faqs/browserconsole/), you should find this error message where you are running your code.  This will help you find and fix errors in the future.

Comment: thnx for the anser.i've removed the breaks and it works!

Answer (score 1):

you are in if , you don't need to use break ;)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Lab 08</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Lab 08</h1>
<script>
    //0:begin
    console.log("la");
    var vandaag = new Date(); //1 //vandaag date.now(in mill sec) of new date
    document.write("vandaag is:" + vandaag + "<br>");//2
    var factuur = new Date("2021-6-16");//3
    var termijn = new Date(86400000 * 30);
    document.write("factuurdatum is:", factuur, "<br>");
    var betaaltijd = (factuur.getTime() + termijn.getTime());//6
    var eenDag = 86400000;
    var betaaldatum = new Date(betaaltijd);//7
    document.write("betaaldatum is:" + betaaldatum + "<br>");//8


    vandaag1 = vandaag.getTime();
    betaaldatum1 = betaaldatum.getTime();
    console.log("la");
    if (vandaag1 < betaaldatum1) {//9a
        alert("meld incassobureau");//9b
    } else {
        var tijd = ((betaaldatum.getTime() - vandaag.getTime()) / eenDag);
        document.write("u hebt nog " + tijd.toFixed(0) + " dagen om te betalen");//11

    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by others, you need to remove `break` statement.

Now, the reason `else` statement is never executed is because the value returned by `if (vandaag1 < betaaldatum1) {` is always true. `vandaag1` has numeric/epoch format of the current time. And `betaaldatum1` has numeric format of sum of `factuur` and `termijn`. Where `factuur` point to 16th of June 2021 and `termijn` points to 31st Jan 1970. Adding the numeric value of both these date gives us 16th July 2021. Which is still greater than current date-time.

So, else statement is not executed until if condition is false, `if` condition will be false only after 16th July 2021. Executed these code then you will always get your else block executed.

Comment: Adding the two time values should give a date for around 16 July, but otherwise, good answer. :-)

Comment: Corrected based on RobG suggestion